# How to create two different cookies or sessions for same web application with different query parameter?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, cookies, struts2

The application is loaded for example on a page like https://dummy.example.com/application?token=JWT_token
For two different tokens the same web page will open but with different data as retrieved from the token.
I am using session to create the user profile and setting it in the session attribute. For the two tabs in the same browser the session and cookie remains the same which is the the one for the page last loaded.It is creating the data inconsistency issues when the user can switch the tab and make changes as the user profile and session is same for the two tabs.
**I want to create two different sessions in two different tabs for the same web app in a single browser. Is it possible by creating two different cookies ?**

Code to set the session attribute

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
uprofile = new UserProfile();
setUserDetails(loginName, "");
session.setAttribute("user",uprof);
```

Comment: Each tab in Chrome (if applicable to your case) is run by a separate process on your computer, so in a sense, they always are in a different session.

Comment: I agree but sessions are created based on the cookie. Same cookie is created for a domain URL. So different tabs will share the same cookie with same JsessionID.

Comment: What are the details you are storing in the cookie?